# Can a man-in-the-middle replay a valid X.509 certificate?

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle, x.509

Consider the following scenario:

1. M (who will later be the man-in-the-middle) connects via https to bank.com. He saves the X.509 certificate (or certificate chain) received from bank.com.
2. Alice starts a https connection to bank.com.
3. M intercepts Alice's TLS messages and responds with corresponding TLS messages. For the certificate, M sends bank.com's certificate from step 1.

Can Alice observe, that the bank.com certificate wasn't sent by bank.com but by M?

*Remark:* In TLS 1.2 it was possible that the certificate included public parameters used for asymmetric encryption during handshake. In this case the attack won't be successful in general, because M misses the corresponding private key from bank.com. But if ephemeral keys are used, this restriction is no longer in place.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of the question I've linked too, i.e. the  server certificate's private key (which is unknown to the attacker)  would be required in all cases to authenticate the server against the client (which is the main point of the server certificate). If you don't think this is a duplicate please make clear how your question is different by editing your question.

Comment: @Steffen: I figured it out. In TLS the point is that the certificate_verify message contains a hash that is generated by the server (resp. by the client if the client authenticates with a certificate) by using the certificates private key (the role of certificate_verify seems not to be mentioned in any of the answers you linked). So the attack described in the question works fine till the moment when the attacker has to sent its  certificate_verify message.

Comment: CertificateVerify is not about verification of the server certificate but about verifying the (optional) client certificate, i.e. it is irrelevant in this case. The digital signature using the servers private key is in the ServerKeyExchange message.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: that is (was?) true <= 1.2, but in 1.3 CertVerify is used for server (always) as well as client (optionally). (And it always signs the whole transcript so far, not just the ServerKX content plus nonces as in <= 1.2.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 & SteffenUllrich: Thanks for the clarification. As you say, the place where the private key of the server certificate is used depends on TLS version. In TLS 1.2 its used to sign keys (and some other data) in the server_key_exchange mesage. In TLS 1.3 its used to sign the transcript contained in the server's certificate_verify message.